# How to write unit test case for Volley-Json custom request using roboelectric?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, android-instrumentation

Please any one help to write test case for android volley. I am using JSON Custom request in my app. I have no idea to write unit test case for this. How to mock api request and response data..? Is it possible to write test case for Volley Json using Roboelectric. Please give suggestion for this. Thanks.